# iOS Device not receiving push using parse. Any ideas?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, pfquery

I am trying to set up parse to send push notifications to users. My code seems ok, everything compiles and something is registered on the Parse website when I send a push, but my phone will not receive any kind of push notification. Nothing. I have followed the parse tutorial, in my AppDelegate.m applicationDidFinishLaunching I have:

```
 UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
  UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                         categories:nil];
[application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

I also implemented :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
currentInstallation.channels = @[ @"global" ];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

}

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application
didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

I want to send a push to a PFUser contained in an array:

```
- (void)pushFriendAtIndex:(NSInteger)index completionHandler:(userCompletionHandler)handler
{
    PFQuery *usernameQuery = [PFUser query];
    [usernameQuery whereKey:@"username" equalTo:[[self.friends objectAtIndex:index] username]];

    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
    [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" matchesQuery:usernameQuery];

    NSString *pushMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"From %@",     self.currentUser.username];
    NSDictionary *pushData = @{@"alert": pushMessage, @"badge": @0, @"sound": @"push.wav"};
    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setQuery:pushQuery];
    [push setData:pushData];
    [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        handler(NO, error);
    }
    else {
        handler(YES, nil);
    }
}];

}
```

I have checked my parse account page and have this:

[image]

The user catcat is correct, so it is registering the push on Parse. What does segment mean? Should it say who the push is sent to?

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked that the targeting you set for the push notification actually match any Installation that has a valid deviceToken stored in the Installations table?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. What is the installations table?

Comment: It is where the PFInstallation objects get saved to. It is available in your dashboard https://parse.com/apps/{YOUR-APP-NICENAME}/collections#class/_Installation

Comment: Okay, took a look at this. There was a single installation. Should there be one installation per device/user or just one for the app? I just deleted that one on the Parse website been running the app again and now nothing appears.

Comment: There should be one for each device. And never, I repeat, never delete stuff there manually, it just messes things up :) You can simply delete the app from your device and re-install it, that should fix the issue. If everything works and you implemented the native code correctly, there should be a new device after you launch the re-installed app the first time.

Comment: okay that worked, there is an installation now for the device. It is possible to send a push notification FROM the simulator to a device right? It's just the simulator can't receive.

Comment: That should be no issue, sending pushes with the Parse SDK from a simulator installation should work as long as you have enabled Client Push in your app settings on parse.com

Comment: The simulator won't create an installation though. Just the device. If I try to send from the simulator though it still registers under the Push section on my dashboard. Phone still receives nothing.

Comment: Well, if it still does not work and you setup everything correctly on your end and going through the Troubleshooting guide for Push Notifications doesn't help either (see https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#troubleshooting/iOS), I would suggest filing a bug report with Parse including a sample project https://www.parse.com/help

Comment: I got it working by targeting device = ios in the  PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query]; So the push works. Is it possible to add a user field to the PFInstallation? I guess I just do this in the app delegate.

Comment: Yes, you can add a column of type Pointer to the Installation class and save a pointer to the user in it, no problem.